# Customize mini frame navigation

Tags: beamer, color, navigation, mini-frames

I'm trying to create my own beamer theme; I want to use a mini frame navigation in headline (included by using `\insertnavigation`) but the colors not working as I want them yet.

Here´s the output of my headline:

[image]

When going forward in the presentation, the current active section is shown in black. How can I change its color to the gold I've already used?

Also I´d like to change the shading of inactive sections to get them a little brighter than they are at the moment.

Here´s the important part of my `colortheme.sty` and the `outertheme.sty`:

```
% Setzt Deep Harlequin (dunkler)  
\definecolor{jvagreen}{RGB}{22, 89, 0}

% Setzt Vivid Gold (dunkler)
\definecolor{jvagold}{RGB}{231, 202, 0}

% Farbe der Elemente der headline
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg = jvagold, bg = jvagreen}

=====================================================================

% Komprimiert die miniframe Kreise auf eine Linie
\beamer@compresstrue


% Definiert die headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{ 
\usebeamercolor{seperation line}
% Bindet die Grafik ein
\includegraphics[width=0.15\paperwidth]{Wappen_JvA}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.85\paperwidth,right]{section in head/foot}
    \rule{0.85\paperwidth}{1pt}
    %Vertikaler Abstand
    \vskip10pt
    %Fügt die Standard-Navi ein (miniframes)
    \insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}
    \vskip8pt
    \rule{0.85\paperwidth}{0.5pt}
    \vskip7.5pt
    % Horizontaler Abstand
    \leftskip=10pt
    % Fügt den frametitle an dieser Stelle ein
    \insertframetitle
    \vskip20pt
    \leftskip=0pt
    \rule{0.85\paperwidth}{1pt}
\end{beamercolorbox} 
}
```

If you have any ideas on how to change it in the way I want it to be or suggestions / improvements to my code, please let me know ;)

Comment: `\insertframetitle` won't be recognized inside the `headline` template. You need to set the `headline` and `frametitle` templates separately.

Comment: Well he's giving me a compile error, but basically it works ;) He inserts the frame title as asked. Could u show me how to separate them correctly?

Comment: You should use `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}` as you did for the `headline`: you have to remove part of the code in your actual `headline` and put it in the `frametitle`.

Comment: Mmmhh yeah, that works, but doesn't give the result I want ... the frame title is supposed to be only in the headline, not on the frame itself a second time.

Comment: @JvA: it is just matter of defining in a proper way the vertical spacing. I think it is perfectly possible get your desired result with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help - now it´s done the way u mentioned by using the frametitle. :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino  can you cook up a small example and answer to this.

Answer (score 6):

As said in the comments, the right way to proceed is to define separately the two templates `headline` and `frametitle`.

Here is a possible implementation (as test image I used the logo of my university):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%=====================================================================
% Color definition

% Setzt Deep Harlequin (dunkler)  
\definecolor{jvagreen}{RGB}{22, 89, 0}

% Setzt Vivid Gold (dunkler)
\definecolor{jvagold}{RGB}{231, 202, 0}

% Farbe der Elemente der headline
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg = jvagold, bg = jvagreen}

%=====================================================================
% Templates - headline, frametitle

\makeatletter
% Komprimiert die miniframe Kreise auf eine Linie
\beamer@compresstrue
\makeatother

% Definiert die headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{ 
\includegraphics[width=0.15\paperwidth]{logopolito} % test logo
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.85\paperwidth,right]{section in head/foot}
    \rule{0.85\paperwidth}{1pt}
    %Vertikaler Abstand
    \vskip10pt
    %Fügt die Standard-Navi ein (miniframes)
    \insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}
    \vskip8pt
    \rule{0.85\paperwidth}{0.5pt}
    \vskip27.5pt % same height of the example provided, but IMHO is too much
    \rule{0.85\paperwidth}{1pt}
\end{beamercolorbox} 
}

% definition of the frametitle
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
\vskip-24pt % to shift up the frametitle
\hbox{ 
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.0675\textwidth]{} % left shift
 \end{beamercolorbox} 
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt]{section in head/foot}
 \insertframetitle
 \end{beamercolorbox} 
 }
}

\begin{document}
\section{Test 1}
\subsection{first}
\begin{frame}{A title}
hello
\end{frame}

\subsection{second}
\begin{frame}{A second title}
hello
\end{frame}

\section{Test 2}
\subsection{first}
\begin{frame}{Another title}
hello
\end{frame}

\subsection{second}
\begin{frame}{A second title}
hello
\end{frame}

\section{Test 3}
\subsection{first}
\begin{frame}{Last title}
hello
\end{frame}

\subsection{second}
\begin{frame}{A second title}
hello
\end{frame}

\subsection{second}
\begin{frame}{A third title}
hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The final result is:

[image]